# Polly IHttpClientFactory and handling 401's (Unauthorised)

Tags: c#, .net-core, polly, fault-tolerance, ihttpclientfactory

I'm using Polly and `IHttpClientFactory` to handle my fault tolerance, which is working fine for retry and circuit breaker in .NET Core 3.1

I'm not trying to handle any 401's, which I can do within the controller, but I can't find a way to refresh the token from the StartUp

This is my policy in startup

```cs
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> httpWaitAndRetryPolicy =
    Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => !r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, sleepDurationProvider: retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryAttempt),
            onRetry: (httpResponseMessage, span, retryCount, ctx) =>
            {
                if (httpResponseMessage.Result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    PerformReauthorazation();
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Retrying({retryCount})...");
            });

private void PerformReauthorazation()
{
    var x = 0;
    //do something
}
```

But this is detached from from the actual controller as you would expect.

To reauthorise I need to call and get a new token to an end-point with all the credentials.

Then I add the following header

```cs
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken.AccessToken);
```

But how do I do this from the StartUp?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/05/re-authorization-and-onretry-with-polly/) or [this](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/refresh-google-access-token-with-polly/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh Token using Polly with Typed Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56976156/refresh-token-using-polly-with-typed-client)