# How to handle Authorization token expiring at the configuration level

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, separation-of-concerns, polly

One way of adding an authorization token to your `HttpRequestMessage` is to simply add it at the configuration level:

```
services.AddHttpClient<INetworkService, NetworkService>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(appConfig.Network.SE);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", TokenGenerator.GetToken());
})
```

I don't want to ping the endpoint for a new authorization token every time I make a request so the token is cached. The logic inside `TokenGenerator` looks in the stored location for a token or creates a new one.

If the token isn't stored, create a new one and return it. If the token is stored, fetch it and return it.

If this kind of authorization was happening at the client level, say in a named or typed client, then I can create a new token as a response to an Unauthorized  StatusCode. **How can we gracefully handle the scenario when the token is being added in the configuration?**

---

I'm been trying to use **Polly** with separation of concerns - *meaning policies are not shoved into the client class* but instead generated and attached at configuration level. I've been unable to find a way to mutate the request header in order to add the new token.

```
return Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(response => response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    .RetryAsync(
        retryCount : 1, 
        onRetryAsync: async (responseDelegate, retryNumber, context) =>
        {      
            // Case 1: Token Expired
            ?? how to mutate request message with new auth header???
            // Case 2: Actually unathorized
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh Token using Polly with Typed Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56976156/refresh-token-using-polly-with-typed-client)

Comment: @PeterCsala no, I’m not shoving policy logic into the client.

Comment: You have two options (that I'm aware of) either you replace the client with an instance where the new token is being set, like [this](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/05/re-authorization-and-onretry-with-polly/) or you retrieve the access token from the context and refresh that data inside the context on retry like [this](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/refresh-google-access-token-with-polly/).