# C# how to automate api requests that require a sessionId that expires

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I need to get data from an api that reuqires first getting a sessionId using a username and password.  The sessionId that is provided from the getSession endpoint needs to be passed in with all requests in the header.

I'm able to use httpclient to do all this for making requests, but how can this be automated such that requests can be made on a schedule, for example every 5 minutes? Would I need to cache the provided session so that I can reuse it as long as it is alive?  I'm guessing you wouldn't want to request a new sessionId with every request.  How, would I know that it is alive without specifically making some kind of request to the api?

Any pointers to examples or resources on this type of automated api request process would be welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Refresh a token using IHttpClientFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204350/how-to-refresh-a-token-using-ihttpclientfactory)

Comment: Or check this one as well: [Refresh Token using Polly with Typed Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56976156/refresh-token-using-polly-with-typed-client)